# MongoDB - Get aggregated difference between two date fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have one collection called lists with following fields:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a7c9f60c05d7370232a1b73"), "created_date" : ISODate("2018-11-10T04:40:11Z"), "processed_date" : ISODate("2018-11-10T04:40:10Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a7c9f85c05d7370232a1b74"), "created_date" : ISODate("2018-11-10T04:40:11Z"), "processed_date" : ISODate("2018-11-10T04:41:10Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a7c9f89c05d7370232a1b75"), "created_date" : ISODate("2018-11-10T04:40:11Z"), "processed_date" : ISODate("2018-11-10T04:42:10Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a7c9f8cc05d7370232a1b76"), "created_date" : ISODate("2018-11-10T04:40:11Z"), "processed_date" : ISODate("2018-11-10T04:42:20Z") }
```

I need to find out aggregated result in the following format (the difference between processed_date and created_date):

```
  [{
    "30Sec":count_for_diffrence_1,
    "<=60Sec":count_for_diffrence_2,
    "<=90Sec":count_for_diffrence_3
  }]
```

One more thing if we can find out how may item took 30 sec, 60 sec and so on, also make sure that the result for <=60 Sec should not come in <=90Sec.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query in 3.6 version.

`$match` with `$expr` to limit the documents where the time difference is 90 or less seconds.

`$group` with `$sum` to count different time slices occurences.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"$expr":{"$lte":[{"$subtract":["$processed_date","$created_date"]},90000]}}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":null,
    "30Sec":{"$sum":{"$cond":{"if":{"$eq":[{"$subtract":["$processed_date","$created_date"]},30000]},"then":1,"else":0}}},
    "<=60Sec":{"$sum":{"$cond":{"if":{"$lte":[{"$subtract":["$processed_date","$created_date"]},60000]},"then":1,"else":0}}},
    "<=90Sec":{"$sum":{"$cond":{"if":{"$lte":[{"$subtract":["$processed_date","$created_date"]},90000]},"then":1,"else":0}}}
  }}
])
```

Note if the created date is greater than processed date you may want to add a condition to look only for values where difference is between 0 and your requested time slice.

Something like

```
{$and:[{"$gte":[{"$subtract":["$processed_date","$created_date"]},0]}, {"$lte":[{"$subtract":["$processed_date","$created_date"]},60000]}]}
```

Comment: Result for "<=60Sec" will come in "<=90Sec". How do I filter that?

Comment: Use `{$and:[{"$gt":[{"$subtract":["$processed_date","$created_date"]},60000]}, {"$lte":[{"$subtract":["$processed_date","$created_date"]},90000]}]}`

Comment: Or you can just do `{"$gt":[{"$subtract":["$processed_date","$created_date"]},60000]}`